# Routing on outgoing data packet in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking

I am currently studying iptables. So far all the articles and howtos I have found on google/duckduckgo has only ever mentioned routing on incoming packets (passing the INPUT och FORWARD chain). I find this strange. Routing must be applied to outgoing packets (passing the OUTPUT chain) as well, right? How else does the kernel know what interface to send them to!?

Comment: See the kernel routing table and [route add](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/route.htm) documentation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, but it needs to be improved before it is worth migrating.

Comment: [This](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) schematic from [this](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/iptables-manual.html) article is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the primary purpose of the routing table -- to determine how to get outbound packets TCP/IP packets on to their destination.